# Утечка памяти в stringstream

Tags: c++

Имеется черновой код программы, которая ищет числа дающие в третьей или четвертой или пятой степени полиндромы. Сама программа уже написана как нужно, всё работает, всё путём, вопрос о другом.
При работе этого кода:

```
long double numb;
std::stringstream stream;
std::string check;
bool flag;
for (int i = 0; true; ++i) {
    for (int degree = 3; degree < 6; ++degree) {
        numb = pow(i, degree);
        stream << numb;
        stream >> check;
        stream.clear();
        flag = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < check.size() / 2; ++j) {
            if (check[j] != check[check.size() - 1 - j]) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag)
            break;
    }
    if (flag)
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
system("pause");
```

наблюдается утечка памяти и уже к седьмой минуте работы процесс уверено пожирает больше 800мб памяти. Выявил лишь, что виновником является мой метод преобразования числа в строку через поток, где-то в этих строках и происходит утечка:

```
stream << numb;
stream >> check;
stream.clear();
```

В чём именно причина утечки? Куда и на что уходит память?

Comment: вы из внешнего цикла где выходите?

Comment: Нигде, он бесконечный.

Comment: и вы считаете это нормальным поведением?

Comment: У вас в программе нет "утечки" памяти, а есть постоянное выделение все большего и большего количества "неутекшей" памяти, как правильно указано в ответе @Croessmah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как таковой утечки нет, но есть кое-что другое. Вы пишите в `stream` всё дальше и дальше, без его очистки, поэтому данные в нем накапливаются.

```
stream.clear();
```

это не очищает буфер, а лишь сбрасывает флаги ошибок.
Таким образом при повторяющихся записях

```
stream << numb;
```

размер буфера в `stream` становится всё больше и больше.
В качестве варианта решения можно установить новое значение для содержимого буфера:

```
stream.clear();
stream.str("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Утечек в программе нет (я их не нашел), но есть другая проблема. Ваш код похоже надеется, что double может хранить достаточно большие числа без потери точности. А это не так. Более того, он надеется, что функция pow работать "правильно" (тут недавно был вопрос о  ней).

Например, уже при i = 16 и degree = 5, получается check=1.04858e+06. Проверять такое на "симметрию" нет смысла. А когда i достигает 100, то все результаты уже представлены в таком виде.

Еще раз, рассуждать о палиндромности можно только для целых чисел, записанных просто числами, а не в научной форме.

Почему же "утечка" - нет утечки, просто менеджер памяти выделил память с запасом.

Но что делать, если очень сильно хочется найти? использовать целые числа для результата или найти любой класс для работы с  большими числами.

Comment: я тоже не нашел утечку